# SSH port forwarding breaks the original port?

Tags: networking, ssh, port-forwarding, port, ssh-tunnel

I have a device configured to use port forwarding via ssh to allow access remotely. This works fine, except that for most of the forwarded ports the host seems to now refuse direct connections with the original (before forwarding) ports, where it used to work fine. The command I'm using to start the forwarding is  the following:

```
ssh -o ExitOnForwardFailure=yes -R 50001:localhost:5001 -R 50000:localhost:5000 -R 50022:localhost:22 username@remoteserver.example.com
```

I'm able to connect to the services through the (slow, though a cellular connection) remote server, by connecting to (for example) remoteserver.example.com:50001. All 3 services work fine this way. The problem is that I'm unable to connect over the local network to the services at hostname.local:5001. The same is true for the service at ports 50000/5000. However, connecting to port 22 to ssh in directly still works fine, despite the other services failure to connect.

Is this expected behavior? How can I fix this?

If it's relevant the other two services (that I'm having trouble with) are webpages hosted by flask, and this is running on Raspbian Stretch.

Comment: If I'm understanding the setup right, this doesn't make any sense at all. Having ssh forward to a port shouldn't block it, so I don't know what'd cause the symptom you describe. But also, the remote access shouldn't work, because by default `-R` binds the listening socket to the local loopback interface (on the remote system), so it won't receive connections made to remoteserver.example.com. Have I misunderstood the setup here?

Comment: Thanks for the response, @GordonDavisson, It's been a while since I originally set up they system, so I don't remember too many details of how I originally did it (and going to bed now, so can't check for details until tomorrow), but according to this source https://www.ssh.com/ssh/tunneling/example the -R option can be used for remote forwarding in the way I described (and evidently is), as long as the 'GatewayPorts yes' option is specified in the sshd_config